# How does Android's ImageWriter work under the hood?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-image

I have a custom Camera2 OpenGL pipeline to process frames from a Camera device.

I have two target `EGLSurface`s that I just send the EXTERNAL_OES OpenGL texture to using a pass-through Shader.
This is pretty efficient, but I found the `ImageWriter` API from Android and it seems to do exactly what I am doing with my OpenGL pipeline - just with way less code.

I'm wondering how this compares to an OpenGL pipeline? Does `ImageWriter` have any other kind of extra features or optimizations? Does `ImageWriter` skip the PRIVATE -> RGB conversion that happens in an EXTERNAL_OES OpenGL texture?

Is it recommended to switch to `ImageWriter` instead of my custom C++ OpenGL pipeline?

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of: https://cs.android.com/ and should you wish to look at internals like: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/ImageWriter.java

Comment: Yea I need to browse more on their page. Guessing the answer is somewhere in the C++ code thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenGL pipeline loads the camera frames as textures into the GPU, lets you apply any sort of rendering effect to them, and then lets you output the resulting frames to wherever you're wanting them to go.

An ImageWriter is just a queue of Android graphics buffers. It doesn't do anything besides move buffers from producer A to consumer B.

So what is the purpose of your OpenGL pipeline? If you're not applying any edits in your shader code, why does it exist? For making multiple copies of your input frames, or to convert the frames to RGB? Or something else?
ImageWriter is more power-efficient since it doesn't need to spin up the GPU to do work, but it's much less flexible and capable than EGL.

Comment: The purpose of my OpenGL pipeline is because it writes the textures into **two** separate output Surfaces (one ImageReader and one MediaRecorder), which is something ImageWriter can't do afaik?

Comment: No, ImageWriter can't have multiple outputs, so it can't replace your OpenGL pipeline here.  Though if you're not doing any edits, you could request two outputs from the camera directly.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks Eddy.